# SQL Performance when quering for a time interval

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance

I have one table of `tickets` containing three relevant columns: `id`, `start` and `finish` where `start` and `finish` are `timestamps`.

I have a second table (`intervals`) with only one relevant column which is `time point`. `time_point` is also a `timestamp`. `time_point` is always every 15 minutes. That is content of this second table is:

```
8:00
8:15
8:30
...
```

The first table (ticket) has 4 millions of records. The second has only 96  records (24 * 4).

I have to select how many tickets are open at any `time_point`

I wrote the following query: (simplified version)

```
select * 
from interval, ticket 
where (finish is null or finish > time_point)
      and start < time_point
```

which works but it is too slow. The problem is that there is no real join between both tables and a I presume that a full table scan is performed for every row.

How can I get better performance here?

Thanks!

EDIT: This is an Oracle DB.

Comment: I doubt that this query works in every situation. `start < time_point` should remove all rows where `finish` lands in first interval because `start` probably cannot be less than zero. It also removes all rows where `start` and `finish` fall to same interval, but that might be intentional. If `finish` is null then that row is cross joined to entire `interval` table. And if `finish` can be `00:00` then it will never be returned.

Comment: If you really need simple (computable) intervals than you should truncate `finish` to first earlier 15-minute mark. If you need more general approach I would try with interval table stating both start and end of an interval and join on `ticket.finish >= interval.start and ticket.finish < interval.end`. Note that last interval must end in 24:00, not 00:00.

Comment: What database system you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you dont need to cross join or create an interval table.
Instead try following:

```
> select count(*), tsd from (
>         select 
>         /****************************************************************
>         Now 
>         1- bring your finish column into the format you need: HH24:MI
>         2- truncate its content down to the interval the row belongs to
>         ****************************************************************/
>         to_char(dt,'HH24')|| decode(trunc(to_char(dt,'MI')/15) * 15,0,'00',trunc(to_char(dt,'MI')/15)*15)
> tsd
>         from (
>             select  nvl( finish  ,to_date('31.12.2999', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))   dt      -- 
>               from tickets 
>               /****************************************************************
>               Now Filter out your tickets(before truncate), to find the relevant 
>               tickets for your period use a Parameter date and compare it to the
>               start and end columns nvl( finish  ,to_date('31.12.2999', dd.mm.yyyy'))
>               ****************************************************************/
>               where P_YOUR_PARAM_DATE between start 
>                                       and nvl( finish  ,to_date('31.12.2999', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))
>             ) dat  
>      )  group by tsd order by tsd ;
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to speed this up is to include the finish column in a composite index so there's no need to read from the table to fetch that value:

```
                create index IX_Tickets on Tickets(start,finish)
```

P.S. Drop any simple index on Tickets.start as well.

P.P.S. Please clarify:  `8:00, 8:15` in your `intervals` table are not `timestamp` data type. Did you elminate the date element in your question for the sake of simplicity?

Comment: yes I did. This is the simplified version for tables and queries.

Comment: Don't "simplify" for queries. If Ticket.start is actually a timestamp with date and time chunks, create a table of the actual timeslots for your specified date-time-range, including the date element (use a CTE if available) and then do your comparison of those slots to Ticket.start and Ticket.finish. The composite index will help.